# Is there a way to get a varnish image from an earlier version than 6.0

Tags: docker, varnish

```
 varnish:
  image: varnish:3.0
  restart: always
  depends_on:
   - apache
  networks:
   - frontend
   - backend
   - traefik
  volumes:
   - ./docker/varnish:/etc/varnish
  ports:
   - 6081:6081
```

I was trying to install an earlier version of Varnish, but the earliest is 6.0 according to Dockerhub and I need a Varnish version where the VCL version is lower than 4.0.

```
vcl 4.0;

backend default {
  .host = "apache:80";
}
```

This is what I had, but the VCL version of the vcl file in my production server is different. I need to install an earlier version. Is there a docker box for varnish with an earlier version so I don't get an error due to some error coming from the VCL file?

Answer (score 0):

### Disclaimer

> VCL versions are not specifically linked to Varnish versions.
>
> VCL syntax 4.0 was introduced in Varnish 4, which is end-of-life and honestly really old.
>
> Every Varnish version since 4.0 supports this syntax, even Varnish 6.
>
> VCL version 4.1 was introduced to support specific breaking changes in Varnish 6.
>
> That means Varnish 6 supports both VCL syntax version 4.0 and 4.1.

### The short answer

There are no pre-Varnish 6 images for Docker. Varnish Software's involvement in the official Docker image only started in 2019.

### Why use an older version?

On the one hand one could argue that you can create the image yourself by leveraging the [official Varnish Cache packages](https://packagecloud.io/varnishcache/). They go all the way back to version 3.0.

However, Varnish 4.0, which introduced VCL syntax 4.0, was released in 2014. This means you're dealing with a VCL file that dates back from before 2014.

I'm not sure it's a good idea to run a VCL config that is so old. If you're stuck with an old version, there is a tool out there that will convert the VCL file into the new syntax. See https://github.com/fgsch/varnish3to4 for more info

### About your VCL example snippet

I noticed you used the following VCL snippet:

```
backend default {
  .host = "apache:80";
}
```

2 remarks about this:

1. Port information needs to be defined via the `.port` backend property
2. Port `80` is the standard port, you can even omit the value

### My advice

I strongly advise using the `varnish:stable` Docker image, which refers to the `Varnish Cache 6.0 LTS` release. This is a *Long Term Supported* version that receives frequent updates and that is kept stable by Varnish Software.

Older versions of the Varnish Docker image don't exist, but even if you would create a custom image using an older version, you face quite some risks.

These older versions of Varnish are no longer maintained: they might contain bugs and aren't considered stable.

You're better off refactoring your VCL to support the VCL 4.0 syntax.

> Although I have a strong opinion about using the stable version of the software, I'm definitely willing to listen to your story and to your arguments in favor of using the old VCL syntax.